How to save the fail logs of an app in a file or something similar?
I have a very complex app focused on a private audience and for professional use. It is not in the Play Store or other stores. Recently users have encountered serious and non-replicable bugs that if I were able to read the logs I could easily find the problem. With that idea in mind, I want to create a file or something similar when the app fail, where the fail log information is stored. Is there a way to do this?

Once upon a time there was a popular library called ACRA.  It was a very popular crash reporting app.  It looks like it's still active as a project, it might fit your needs.  https://github.com/ACRA/acra  IIRC, it comes built in with a system to upload logs to a server if you want it to.
